# Existence of a reversible distribution for Markov chains with compact state space

Tags: markov-chains

[Krylov–Bogolyubov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov%E2%80%93Bogolyubov_theorem) shows that for any Markov chain on a Polish space $S$ that satisfies suitable conditions, there exists a stationary probability measure. My question is that under what conditions there exists a **stationary and reversible** probability measure? I only need the case where $S$ is compact.

Note: If $S$ is countable, then Kolmogorov's cycle condition gives an answer (see [this](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matsr/ProbII/Lec8.pdf)).